# How to set NSMutableAttributedString into two lines

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsdictionary, nsmutableattributedstring

I want to create a single `UILablel` like this.
[image]

I want to set year font to HElvaticaNeu-medium and the 2015 into HelvaticaNeu. And I need these two strings to appear in 2 lines just like in this image.

How I can do this. I set two seperate `NSMutableAttributedString` in this way.

```
UIFont *helMedium = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:12.0];
NSDictionary *mediumDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: helMedium forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *mAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Year :" attributes: mediumDict];

UIFont *helNormal = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0];
NSDictionary *normalDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: helNormal forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *nAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"2016" attributes: normalDict];
```

Now how should I set this 2 strings in two lines?
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: "\n" character is what you are looking for. Add it in helMedium stings end or helNormal string's start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to append the second string to first string

Use this code.

```
UIFont *helMedium = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:12.0];
NSDictionary *mediumDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: helMedium forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *mAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Year :" attributes: mediumDict];

UIFont *helNormal = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0];
NSDictionary *normalDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: helNormal forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
NSMutableAttributedString *nAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n2016" attributes: normalDict];

[mAttrString appendAttributedString:nAttrString];

label.attributedText = mAttrString;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *nAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n2016" attributes: normalDict];

NSMutableAttributedString  *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
[attString appendAttributedString: mAttrString];
[attString appendAttributedString: nAttrString];

// label.attributedText = attString
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  UIFont *helMedium = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:12.0];
  NSDictionary *mediumDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: helMedium forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
  NSMutableAttributedString *mAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Year :" attributes: mediumDict];

  UIFont *helNormal = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0];
  NSDictionary *normalDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: helNormal forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
  NSMutableAttributedString *nAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n2016" attributes: normalDict];

  [mAttrString appendAttributedString:nAttrString];
  _yearLabel.attributedText = mAttrString;
  [_yearLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
```

If you want more space around text in UILabel, specify width and height constraints for the same.